# Positioning elements with material design

Tags: css, polymer, material-design

Im trying to learn how to make responsive web UI's while using google material design guidelines.
Between all the material design implementations for now I have chosen to work with Polymer material design.

The thing which im not sure about is how to position my elements(/components)
inside the page.
For example I have written this simple main page

```
<div>
    <div horizontal center-justified layout>
        <div>
            <paper-button id="my" raised class="mainContentButton">Raised button</paper-button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <paper-button raised class="mainContentButton">Raised button</paper-button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div horizontal center-justified layout>
        <div>
            <paper-button raised class="mainContentButton">Raised button</paper-button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <paper-button raised class="mainContentButton">Raised button</paper-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
.mainContentButton {
width: 35vw;
height: 25vw;
background: #03a9f4;
```

}

My intentions is to have 4 big buttons, covering most of the page while being centers in the page (horizontaly and verticaly)
for the horizontal part I have found somewhere in the vague parts of the polymer material docs about the "horizontal center-justified layout" attributes which I gave each div. for the vertical centering I couldn't find any solution.

Note: Im coming from a background of using bootstrap grid system for positioning, meaning using classes for divs like row&col for positioning elements in the page.
Now im just trying to understand if material design (in polymer?)
comes with any tools used for positioning elemnts in the page, or that for that I need to have a different approach (using css, or using other front-end frameworks)

Any help is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Flexbox for doing this. there is even an include you can use:
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout

Comment: I have started using polymer layout attributes after posting this question
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380199/positioning-elements-with-material-design#)
should I prefer iron flex layout over it? should I use both? (im a bit confused for having number of options for this from polymer)

Also is using this polymer set of attributes and elements should almost completely remove my use of writing direct css for positioning elements?

Comment: It depends. The layout classes are part of the `iron-flex-layout` element (https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/classes/iron-flex-layout.html). You can use either the normal CSS classes or use the mixins (see the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) for more infos). Mixins are more code to write, but they can be useful if you want to change layout based on media-queries

Comment: So should I prefer using the css classes of iron flex over the layout attributes? (if so what is the reason? more options there?)
and I tried to read about the mixins but I couldn't understand how to use them and why (they seem to be less readable and useable) do you have any example by any chance that could explain to me the use for the mixin?

Comment: This guide might be of help: https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout